# Update tables in sql with strlen or trim

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, database

So, what i have is a table with a cell that has this value `*0000123*`

What i need is to pick that cells values and remove the "*" on both sides and paste it in another cell.

To be removed: The ASTERISK symbol from the text.

How can i manage to edit the inside value in sql without using php in the middle? (Direct input would be the thing)

Comment: Sample data, please (input, desired output). I don't get the question, your sample contains no `*`, yet you say you want to remove the `*`s??

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense from the information you have provided. There is no '*' on either side of the value '0000123'. Please clarify.

Comment: So, you have a string like xyz0000123zyx or what * are you talking about?

Comment: You have also tagged both 'MySQL' and 'SQL Server', which is it?

Comment: I am talking about the symbol ASTERISK=*, i want to remove this symbol from the "equation"

Comment: @Romain i didn't used the code tagging, so the asterisk disapeared, see now that a folk edited it (Thanks to him)

Comment: @weenoid Is sql server, i'm sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be the `REPLACE()` function you're looking for:

```
DECLARE @Example varchar(max) = '*0000123*'
SELECT REPLACE(@Example, '*', '')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `REPLACE` in SQL-Server and MySql:

```
SELECT REPLACE(MyVal, '*', '') As NewValue
FROM Table
```

T-SQL: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx

MySql: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_replace